# Does an operating system give out any kind of signal before going into sleep mode?

Tags: operating-systems

In other words, does a running application have any way to know that the computer is going into sleep mode?

Comment: Similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228288/how-can-i-know-when-windows-is-going-into-out-of-sleep-or-hibernate-mode

Answer (score 3):

Windows certainly does. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/power/power-management-portal .

An application can even inform the system that sleep or hibernate should not occur, because the app is busy - see the `SetThreadExecutionState` API.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will send all applications the
[WM_POWERBROADCAST message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/power/wm-powerbroadcast).

The application will receive the message in its message-pump and can then
know that the computer is going into a low-power state.

The system allows approximately two seconds for an application to handle this notification. If an application is still performing operations after its time allotment has expired, the system may interrupt the application.